# How to the get the Output directory from a Delphi DPROJ file?

Tags: delphi, project, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I have the file path of a Delphi Project file:

```
var MyProjectFile := 'C:\MyProject\MyProject.dproj';
```

Now I need to get the file path of the EXE file compiled from this Delphi project, having only this information.

In my naivety, I assume that the EXE file is in the same directory as the Delphi Project file. So I try to determine the EXE file path from the Project file path with this code:

```
var ProjectExe :=  System.SysUtils.IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(System.SysUtils.ExtractFilePath(MyProjectFile)) +
      System.IOUtils.TPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MyProjectFile) + '.exe';
```

However, this code gets the correct result only with this setting from the Delphi IDE Project Options:

[image]

So how can I get the compiled EXE file path, if the user has defined a different output directory in Project Options, possibly using the Delphi directory variables? Is it possible to detect the currently set output directory directly from the DPROJ file?

Comment: By default, the EXE is found not next to the DPROJ, but in the `Win32\Debug` folder (or some other platform or configuration, like `Win64\Release`). In the DPROJ file, this is specified like so: `<DCC_ExeOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_ExeOutput>`.

Comment: The Delphi project file and the exe file NOT being in the same folder has been introduced about a decade or so ago

Comment: Does the `$(Platform)` variable ALWAYS resolve to `Win32/Win64`and the `$(Config)`variable ALWAYS resolve to `Debug/Release`? Or can this be configured?

Comment: @DelphiCoder That is highly interesting.

Comment: The different values for $(Platform) can be found in PlatformConst.pas, but not all of them are actually available in any Delphi installation. The default $(Config) values are indeed Release and Debug, but the user can add new configurations with arbitrary names at his will.

Comment: @user1580348 on a side note, just as an FYI, your "naive" code could have been greatly simplified: `var ProjectExe := System.SysUtils.ChangeFileExt(MyProjectFile, '.exe');` Not that it matters in this situation, but it is good to know what the RTL offers, in case you need it in the future.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. The RTL really hides the complexity from "naive" users. That is not irony.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Some DPROJ files do not have the `<DCC_ExeOutput>` tag-pair. Which are the conditions to cause the IDE to not include the `<DCC_ExeOutput>` tag-pair in the DPROJ file?

Comment: It seems that when the Output directory in the IDE's Project Options is EMPTY, then the IDE assumes that the Output directory is `.`? That's what I found out empirically. Is this correct?

Comment: @user1580348: I don't know.

Comment: I can confirm from my tests that when the Output directory in the IDE's Project Options is EMPTY, then the compiler creates the EXE in the same directory as the DPROJ file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry a bit late but the trick is to create a unit from scratch from the pre-build event.

Just copy/paste this line in the pre-build input box:

```
(echo unit ProjectExe;&echo interface&echo const MyProjectExe = '$(OUTPUTPATH)';&echo implementation&echo begin end.) > $(PROJECTDIR)\ProjectExe.pas
```

And include `ProjectExe` in the `uses` clause (even if this file does not yet exists).